# Cleanest solution for Mark Lutz' short "exercise for the criminally insane" - generating even/odd pairs (tuples)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am carefully studying Mark Lutz' [Learning Python, 5th Edition](http://a.co/1jhfrYa).  In Chapter 20 (on comprehensions), Mark compares built-in functions (`map` and `filter`) to comprehensions in terms of syntax.

For example, he compares

```
[x ** 2 for x in range(10)]
```

and

```
list(map((lambda x: x ** 2), range(10)))
```

...which yield the same result of `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]` (the first via a comprehension, the second via `map`).

He then gives a second example in comprehension form only:

> [The following] expression combines even numbers from 0 through 4 with odd numbers from 0 through 4. The `if` clauses filter out items in each iteration:

```
[(x, y) for x in range(5) if x % 2 == 0 for y in range(5) if y % 2 == 1]
```

(...the output of which is `[(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]`.)

But Mark does **not** write out the same functionality using `map`/`filter`, instead leaving the reader with this juicy challenge:

> The map and filter equivalent of this last example would be wildly complex and deeply nested, so I won’t even try showing it here. I’ll leave its coding as an exercise for Zen masters, ex–Lisp programmers, and the criminally insane!

(The example here is an excellent one to highlight differences between `map` and comprehensions, which seem quite similar in many other cases, but which in this case are very different in terms of syntactic complexity.)

I decided to take up the challenge and implement this comprehension in terms of `map` and `filter`.  I have provided my answer, below.

My question is, what is (arguably) the cleanest and clearest, even if it is ugly, way of implementing the above comprehension using `map` and `filter`?

Comment: What is the purpose of your self question and answer? You just want to show us that you where able to do the exercise?

Comment: @KlausD. Stack Overflow encourages posters answering their own question, Q/A style.  In this case, I searched for an answer to this while studying the noted textbook, but did not find one, so I wanted to post a solution for others in the future.

Comment: The second sentence of the quote is actually a nicely wrapped version of "Normal people don't do that.". Even if you belong to one of the three groups the idea of the exercise would be to develop the solution on your own.

Comment: ...as I did.  I doubt my solution is the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach (formatted for readability):

```
list(filter(
    lambda pair: pair[0] % 2 == 0 and pair[1] % 2 == 1,
    reduce(
        lambda a, b: a+b,
        list(map(
            lambda x:
                list(map(
                    lambda y: (x, y),
                    range(5)
                )),
            range(5)
        ))
    )
))
```

(That is for Python 3, assuming you've done `from functools import reduce`.  In Python 2 it is slightly simpler since all the calls to `list` can be removed.)

A great deal of the complexity comes from having to generate the cartesian product of the range with itself using only map/reduce, which is rather cumbersome.  If you allow using `itertools`, things become much simpler:

```
list(filter(
    lambda pair: pair[0] % 2 == 0 and pair[1] % 2 == 1,
    itertools.product(range(5), repeat=2)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best take (it seems the `reduce`, as well as the `lambda`s, are necessary) (if binding is possible in Python instead of the lambdas, I haven't gotten to that section of the book yet):

```
result = reduce(lambda r, g: r.extend(g) or r, 
            list(map(lambda x: 
                    list(map(lambda y: (x, y), 
                        filter(lambda a: a % 2 == 1, range(5)))),
                filter(lambda b: b % 2 == 0, range(5)))),
            [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
f = map(lambda x: 
        list(map(lambda y: 
            (x, y), filter(lambda h: 
                h % 2 == 1, range(5))
            )
        ), 
        filter(lambda g: g % 2 == 0, range(5))
    )

print(list(f))
```

Here is the result:

```
[[(0, 1), (0, 3)], [(2, 1), (2, 3)], [(4, 1), (4, 3)]]
```

Note: the resulted list includes two double parantheses which comes from two list calls. And if two double parentheses make you unease, you can always step over it with a for loop.